# PHP mysqli->real_connect prevent other connection to different database in different script while timing out

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, timeout, connection

On a page, I have 2 different jQuery ajax calls to 2 different php scripts.

In each, a mysqli connection is established with a database on a remote server (2 different remote servers).

Sometimes, the server that the first script is trying to connect to can be offline. When this is the case, the $db->real_connect command timeout (which I set to a few seconds), which isn't an issue.

What I don't understand is that, while the $db->real_connect command is running (waiting for timeout) in the first script, and the second script is ajax-called, the second script will pause at its $db->real_connect line until the first script is done trying to connect.

I thought is might be a mysqli setting but I have max_links and max_persistents both set to no limit (-1). Any other settings relating to this? If not, what is the cause of this behavior?

Here is so abridged code that should replicate the issue :

Page:

```
<script>
var session_id = '<?php echo session_id();?>';
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "script1.php",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Set-Cookie', 'PHPSESSID=' + session_id);
    },
    success: function(result) {
        console.log("Script 1 done");
    }
});
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "script2.php",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Set-Cookie', 'PHPSESSID=' + session_id);
    },
    success: function(result) {
        console.log("Script 2 done");
    }
});
<script>
```

script1.php (offline mysql host) :

```
session_start();
$db = mysqli_init();
$db->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5);
$db->real_connect($host, $username, $pass, $dbname); // This hangs for 5 seconds then fails.
```

script2.php (different mysql host, online) :

```
session_start();
$db = new mysqli($host2, $username2, $pass2, $dbname2); // This also hangs for 5 seconds then succeed.
```

When running the page, after a 5 seconds delay, both logs appear in the console.
If I swap the order of script1 and script2 in the Javascript, "Script 2 done" appears instantly and "Script 1 done" 5 seconds later. It seems like only 1 simultaneous connect operation is allowed, any way around that? How would you solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: are you using sessions? sounds a lot like session blocking to me.

Comment: @smith : Indeed! Sounds like I abridged the code too much, sorry about that. I'll search more info on session blocking.

Comment: `session_write_close();` ias the simple solution

Comment: Thanks, it work great now! If you wanna write an answer, I'll delete mine and accept yours.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to smith in the comments for the solution.

The issue was session blocking. 
As I ignored, the file where PHP write $_SESSION variables for an user is locked once you call session_start(), and no other script can access it until you close or the script using it ends. My second script was waiting for this file to become available.

A simple solution is to add session_write_close() immediately after session_start(), if you don't plan on writing session variables. (The variables stay loaded).

I checked this page for more information : http://konrness.com/php5/how-to-prevent-blocking-php-requests/